# Split and join sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have tables like this :

```
A
```

```
ID      CateName
1       C#, sql
2       ios, c#
3       mvc, sql
4       sql, c#
```

Categories

```
id   Name
1    C#
2    Sql
3    ios
4    mvc
```

I need some thing like that

```
ID    CateID
1     1,2
2     3,1
3     4,2
4     2,1
```

Thanks for explaining and help.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Im sorry for missing. I use sql 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a really bad database design.  However, most databases support aggregate string concatenation, which allows you to do what you want.  For instance in MySQL:

```
select a.id, group_concat(c.id)
from a join
     categories c
     on concat(', ', c.catename, ', ') like concat('%, ', name, ', %')
group by a.id;
```

Comment: i use sql 2012.I'm Sorry for missing